# store and retrieve values in linkedhashmap

Tags: java

I have two different set of values.First set of values i put in a linkedhashmap and take it using a key.now i need to put and take the second set of values using same key.but both set of value are different and the parameters have same name...is it possible?

example: I get three parameters from server namely name,age,class i store it linkedhashmap and take it using name as the key.now iam going to get the second set of values with same parameters name,age,class in the same linkedhashmap..i need to take using the same name as key ..is it possible??

Comment: Considering that a hash map works on the assumption of unique keys, I doubt that this is going to work.  Do you have any other unique piece of data which you could use?

Comment: I am not able to get the last part of your example. Can you just add specific example with what do you expect as output?

Comment: @Deepak name is key of map so make sure it will be unique otherwise value will be updated

Comment: Create a compsite of `AllValues = <Values1,Values2>` and then put in the map as `key: AllValues` pairs

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag I have hashmap A now i put three values in hashmap with some key.Also i get second set of values from server now also i store them in the same hashmap using the same key. wat ll happen?

Comment: the first set of values will get replaced if the second set also has the same key right?

Comment: There is another question similar to this, might help [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447095/java-linkedhashmap-iteration)

Comment: How do you put three values in a map with the same key? That's already not possible for a map unless you make some kind of compound value of your three values and associate that with a key.

Comment: You can use a Multimap. Guava has a few, for example. It also has a Table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should define an object that has fields for each of the values you intend to store, e.g.:

```
public class Thing {
  private final String name;
  private final int age;
  private final String cls;

  // constructor, getters
}
```

Then you'd do something like this to add an element to your map:

```
map.put(name, new Thing(name, age, cls));
```

You can then get back a particular `Thing` by looking it up by name:

```
Thing found = map.get(name);
```

Comment: You've named an instance variable `class`

Comment: @pvg thanks, I caught that in the usage example but forgot to fix the class definition. You're welcome to make such trivial edits yourself, btw.