# HashMap Iteration using a for loop

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I have String array values in a hash map.  I need to retrieve that using for loop and store it in a String array. Could anybody show me how with a simple example?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `values()` method.

```
HashMap<K,V> map = ...;
for(V v : map.values()){
    // Use v 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it by this example:

```
Map<Integer, String> exampleMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (String value : exampleMap.values()) {
            System.out.println("Value : " + value);
     }
```

Comment: There is another similar question [Check This Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447095/java-linkedhashmap-iteration)

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question literally, it seems you have:

```
Map<String, String[]> map;
```

You haven't said what the key type is - assuming String, but doesn't matter for this.

To iterate over the values:

```
for (String[] array : map.values()) {
    // do something with array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm;
int i=0;
for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> e : hm.entrySet())
{
    stringArray[i] = e.getValue();
    i++;

}
```

Assuming that you have Integer keys.

Comment: can u pls explain this if i have more keys with same string array values..same code will work out?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if you have same String values.